# eVar value not getting passed in s.tl call

Tags: adobe-analytics

I have a page that contains a login form. I am calling a separate function (which resides in a separate .js file) on the onsubmit event of the form. Below is the function

```
var LoginClick = function() {

    // Omniture Code
    s.linkTrackVars="events, eVar1";
    s.linkTrackEvents="event1";
    s.events="event1";
    s.eVar1="Login";
    s.tl(true, "o", "Login Clicks");

};
```

while the events data is getting passed on the s.tl call, the evar1 value turns up as "none" in the conversion report. I used a packet sniffer (omnibug) to check the values being passed. Even though s.eVar1 is assigned the value "Login" it does not pass that value.

Ofcourse, s.t() works well (evar value gets passed) but I dont want to do that. 
I have tried s.tl(this, "o"...) which doesnt work either.

What am I doing wrong here?

Appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the space between the comma and `eVar1`

```
s.linkTrackVars="events, eVar1"
```

should be

```
s.linkTrackVars="events,eVar1"
```